# MS SQL: Execute Database Request after Server Start

Tags: sql-server, startup, event

I need to execute a request (Stored Procedure) to MS SQL Server after Windows restart, i.e. as soon as the database is accessible.

How can I do that? Is there a possibility to register a database event that fires after startup or a system event after a service started (here: SQL Server Service)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Start Sql Server agent when sql server starts](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/95659/start-sql-server-agent-when-sql-server-starts)

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [Startup Stored Procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-procoption-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) or schedule a SQL Agent with a Schedule type of "Start automatically when SQL Server Agent Starts".

Answer (score 2):

There is a system stored procedure named sp_procoption that does exactly that. See

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-procoption-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-procoption-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#examples)

Syntax is fairly straight forward.  If you have a procedure named 'my_stored_proc', the syntax is:

```
EXEC sp_procoption @ProcName = N'my_stored_proc'   
, @OptionName = 'startup'   
, @OptionValue = 'on';
```

The only value for @OptionName is 'startup', and the only possible values for @OptionValue are 'on' and 'off.'